How to construct seaborn barplot when groups of bars do not have the same number of hues?
I have a seaborn barplot. There are two groups (two x-axis ticks). The first group has 2 hues/sub-groups/conditions. The second group has 3 hues.
When constructing the barplot, seaborn assumes that there are 3 hues for each group. Thus, it leaves an empty gap where the "third bar" of the first group should be, even though it does not exist.
How do I change the barplot so that:

There is no "third bar" gap
The width of all bars is the same

By the way, in the left subplot, group2 should have a third bar but is left as "n/a" for unrelated reasons.

chatGPT gave me various manual plotting solutions, but ultimately they didn't work. I'm sure if I tried hard enough the manual plotting could work.

Please add your current code and some example data, so that we can better understand your issue.

Will you always just have two groups with 2 or 3 subgroups? Or do you need a more general solution? I think manual plotting will be required for this rather than being able to get seaborn to do this for you.

Sorry Marcello, I'll be sure to do that in the future. Thanks Matt, I only have 2 and 3 subgroups, and fortunately, I see that your solution accounts for a more general case.

Here's one way to do it that requires manipulating the Rectangle patch positions made by the barplot command:
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

# some data
data = {
    "group": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "measure": [0.7, 0.75, 0.78, 0.8, 1.3],
    "hue": [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = sns.barplot(data=df, x="group", y="measure", hue="hue")

# get xy positions of rectangles in bar
rects = {}
for p in fig.get_children():
    if isinstance(p, Rectangle):
        if p.get_height() in data["measure"]:
            # rectangle is one of the bars
            xy = p.get_xy()
            rects[xy[0]] = p

# number of values in each group
num_in_groups = df.groupby("group").count()["measure"].values

x0 = min(rects.keys())  # x-position of first bar
pad = 0.02  # some padding between groups

# sort bars on x-position
rects = sorted(rects.items())
width = rects[0][1].get_width()  # bar widths

tickpos = [
    x0 + (width * num_in_groups[0]) / 2,
    x0 + pad + (width * num_in_groups[0]) + (width * num_in_groups[1]) / 2
]

i = 0
for _, rect in rects:
    rect.set(x=x0)
    x0 += width
    i += 1
    if i == num_in_groups[0]:
        # add padding between groups
        x0 += pad

# reset the group labels
fig.set_xticks(tickpos, fig.get_xticklabels())

# reset the x-axis limits
edgepad = 0.05
fig.set_xlim([rects[0][0] - edgepad, rects[0][0] + width * sum(num_in_groups) + pad + edgepad])



Thanks Matt! I adjusted your code to account for the fact that you are indexing bars according to their height. In my data, I did a groupby function to get those heights (which are means), but it turns out that those heights are not a perfect match with the groupby-calculated heights, requiring that I index bars based on the closest height match. The other problem was that I needed to also adjust error bar positions. This was difficult in seaborn, and required that I manually re-plot them.
I didn't mention this in my original post, and I should have.

The example below gets the axis object, and then adjusts the location of the first x tick in order to make it centred:
#Bar plot
ax = sns.barplot(df, x='group', y='measure', hue='hue')

#Modify location of the first x tick only
ax.set_xticks([-0.14] + ax.get_xticks()[1:])

Before:

After:


Reproducible example
import seaborn as sns

#
#Synthetic data
#
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'measure': np.concatenate([10 + np.random.randn(200),
                               20 + np.random.randn(200),
                               15 + np.random.randn(200)]), 
    'group': np.random.randint(low=1, high=3, size=600),
    'hue': np.repeat(['hue 1', 'hue 2', 'hue 3'], repeats=200)
})

df = df.loc[~( (df.group == 1) & (df.hue == 'hue 3') )]

#
# Initial bar plot
#
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = sns.barplot(df, x='group', y='measure', hue='hue')
ax.figure.set_size_inches(7.5, 2.8)

#Report the initial location of the x labels
print('Original tick locations:', ax.get_xticks())

#Modify location of the first x tick only
ax.set_xticks([-0.14] + ax.get_xticks()[1:])


Thanks Muhammed. While this is a nice simple solution, I want to remove the gap in between the two groups that is caused by the fact that seaborn assumes there is a "third bar" for group1, even though it does not exist. I ended up going with Matt's solution.
